# Does anyone know of a good app/tool that allows you to edit MP4 files?

Tags: mp4

I need to be able to increase the volume, cut out silence, add silence etc. for mp4 files. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: (Sorry for the spammer, I've actually never seen that happen here before quite like that, though I'm relatively new.)  This may not be the best forum for this question, since we're mostly about programming questions.  But you may have better luck over at superuser.com with this.  (Same venue, different topic.)

Comment: By general internet standards he was pretty tame, but by Stack Overflow standards he was decidedly rude :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I thought you were asking about tools to edit the mp4 bitstream. Which I am interested in. I use VLC player for this, because it will give me a log file with errors when the MP4s I create don't work, but I am interested in better tools.

For editing mp4s youtube.com/editor is free, cross platform compatible.